# How to add text size to a ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I add a text size code here to reduce the default size. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.xxx;

public class Score extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lstView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_main);

        mainView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainRanking);
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        List<Ranking> mainRanking = db.getRanking();
        if(mainRanking.size() > 0)
        {
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,mainRanking);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="ListViewTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And then add this to your `ListView` tag:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainRanking"
    android:theme="@style/ListViewTheme"
    .../>
```